# ruby restclient timeout does not work properly, it throws exception after double the defined timeout

Tags: ruby, timeout, rest-client

Noticed that [Ruby RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) does not follow the given timeout parameter precisely, however it works by doubling the current timeout setting.

Has anyone noticed the same? attached a test code example below.

As httpbin.org is having max delay 10, we need to use small timeouts:

```
  def test_timeout(delay)
    start = Time.now.to_i
    RestClient::Request.execute(url:     "http://httpbin.org/delay/10",
                                method:  'GET',
                                timeout: delay)
    return 0
  rescue RestClient::Exceptions::ReadTimeout => exception
    endtime = Time.now.to_i
    return endtime - start
  end

pry(main)> test_timeout 1
RestClient.get "http://httpbin.org/delay/10", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"

=> 3

pry(main)> test_timeout 5
RestClient.get "http://httpbin.org/delay/10", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"

=> 10
```

Using Ruby RestClient 2.0.2 and also tested with 2.1.0.rc1

Also tested with read_timeout and open_timeout parameters, which had the same

```
  def test_timeout(delay)
    start = Time.now.to_i
    RestClient::Request.execute(url: "http://httpbin.org/delay/10",
                                method: 'GET',
                                open_timeout: 1,
                                read_timeout: delay)
    return 0
  rescue RestClient::Exceptions::ReadTimeout => exception
    endtime = Time.now.to_i
    return endtime - start
  end

pry(main)> test_timeout 2
RestClient.get "http://httpbin.org/delay/10", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"

=> 4
pry(main)> test_timeout 3
RestClient.get "http://httpbin.org/delay/10", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"

=> 6
```

Comment: Potentially of note: httpbin.org/delay has a max delay of 10seconds.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://engineering.wework.com/ruby-users-be-wary-of-net-http-f284747288b2)

Comment: Thank you Sean, you are right regarding the httpbin.org max delay. Its 10 secs.

Comment: I modified a bit the examples above. Now using smaller timeouts (below 10). The effect is the same.

Comment: Thank you Marcin!

Seem that's its a wanted feature on Net::HTTP library. Ruby 2.5 should have a parameter to over ride the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a summary,

its a wanted feature on Net::HTTP library. Ruby 2.5 should have a parameter to over ride the feature.

More information from https://engineering.wework.com/ruby-users-be-wary-of-net-http-f284747288b2

Thank you all regarding you replies!

Answer (score 1):

Timeout = read_timeout + open_timeout

open_timeout: is the time after which if the connection fails to establish, the request will be rejected

read_timeout:  the time you are willing to wait for some data to be received from the server

```
  RestClient::Request.execute(url: "http://httpbin.org/delay/#{delay * 10}",
                            method: 'GET',
                            timeout: 1)
```

Comment: The initial examples shows that RestClient doubles the time we shall wait, even if the open_timeout is 1 and read_timeout is 3 then the actual timeout occurs at ~6seconds.